# Software to find zero divisors of a ring

Tags: matlab, mathematica, abstract-algebra

Are there some programs with packages that help to list all [zero-divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor) of the ring we desired? especially for the [ring of Gaussian integers modulo $n$, $\mathbb{z}_n[i]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2160330/about-ring-of-gaussian-integers-modulo-n).

Also want to find which of the product of ring elements will result in 0.
I wish to get the details if any. I am new to programming languages, this is because I want to get help to verify my theoretical results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is a [Computer Algebra System (CAS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system). You could find a [list in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems).

I don't know which one suits your particular interest, although [Singular](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/) seems to be a good candidate.